# Tao Analysis. Definition of positive rational numbers.

Tags: analysis

Tao Analysis. Definition of positive rational numbers.

> Definition $4.2.6.$ A rational number $ x$ is said to be positive iff we have
> $x = a/b$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$. It is said to be negative iff
> we have $x = −y$ for some positive rational $y$ ($i.e., $$x$ = $(−a)/b$ for some
> positive integers $a$ and $b$).

My question: Does not $x = a/b$ for some negative integers $a$ and $b$ satisfy? as in $x = -2/-3$. So why does this definition use iff?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Definition $4.2.6.$ A rational number $ x$ is said to be positive iff we have
> > $x = a/b$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$.
>
> Why does this definition use iff?

Every definition in mathematics uses "if and only if"; try to come up with one that doesn't!

> Does $x = a/b$ for some negative integers $a$ and $b$ not satisfy?

1. The above definition can be written $$\forall x{\in}\mathbb
       Q\;\left(x>0\iff\exists a{,}b{>}0\:\:x=\frac ab\right).$$

   $\implies$ direction:

   - Now, if $x$ equals $\dfrac{-8}{-3}$ or $\dfrac{-24}{-9}$ or $\dfrac{16}{6}$ (so, $x$ is positive), then
     $x=\dfrac{\mathbf8}{\mathbf3},$ that is, $$x=\frac ab\text{ for
     }\mathbf{some}\text{ pair of positive integers }a\text{ and }b;$$
     here, we can choose $(16,6)$ instead of $(8,3),$ but $(-8,-3)$ won't
     work.

   $\impliedby$ direction:

   - If $x$ equals $\dfrac{-8}{-3}$ (so, $x=\dfrac{\mathbf8}{\mathbf3},$ that is, $x=\dfrac ab\text{ for
     }\mathbf{some}\text{ pair of positive integers }a\text{ and }b$),
     then $x$ is positive.
2. *A less technical explanation.*

   Each positive rational number $r$ can be expressed as an non-simplified fraction
   $F_1$ of integers with numerator and denominator **both negative**;
   when these two negative signs are dropped, we obtain a non-simplified fraction
   $F_2$ of integers with numerator and denominator **both positive**;
   it is $F_2,$ not $F_1,$ that the above definition is using to define
   $r$ as positive.

   This alternative definition is equivalent to the above one:

   > > Definition $4.2.6.$***Alt*** $\;\;$ A rational number $ x$ is said to be positive iff we have $x = a/b$ for some **negative** integers $a$
   > > and $b.$

   If we adopt this definition, then we need to choose $F_1,$ not
   $F_2.$

Comment: Thank you again @ryang.  And what's this called if $\forall x{\in}\mathbb Q\;\left(x>0\iff\exists a{,}b{<}0\:\:x=\frac ab\right)$?  Can we say "A rational number x is said to be positive iff we have x=a/b for some negative integers a and b"?

Comment: It's just writing out the theorem symbolically to clarify its structure. `⟺` means if and only if, `A⟹B` means B if A, while `A⟸B` means A if B. Please ignore this part if you have not encountered these symbols before; they are not essential to your Query or my Answer.

Comment: And another question: "here, we can choose (16,6) instead of (8,3), but (−8,−3) won't work.", you mean"$x=\dfrac{-8}{-3} \implies  x=\dfrac{\mathbf8}{\mathbf3},$".  Can we just say "$x=\dfrac{-8}{-3} \implies  x=\dfrac{-8}{-3} $" to maintain the consistency with $x=\dfrac ab$ when $a$ and $b$ are negative integers.  @ryang

Comment: Yes, in that case, just change the definition so that it requests for a negative $(a,b)$ pair instead of a positive $(a,b)$ pair! I've expanded my answer to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 6):

The original definition, made more verbose, is the following:

> A rational number $x$ is said to be a positive rational number if and only if **there exists** some positive integer $a$ and some positive integer $b$ such that $x=\frac ab$. A rational number $x$ is said to be a negative rational number if and only if there exists a positive rational $y$ such that $x=-y$.

The key point to highlight here is "there exists". This means that the definition only "**cares**" about positive integers, and such a counter-example is **not relevant**.

If I have to explain this further, please tell me.

Comment: So if it cares about negative integers, Can I conclude this "A rational number $x$ is said to be a positive rational number if and only if there exists some negative integer a and some negative integer b such that $x=\frac ab$"?

Comment: If you change it that way, it still works. In that case it no longer cares about positive integers,